# Python script doesn't work with double click

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7

I have a very basic problem, but I cannot find a solution in older answers.
When I double click on a python script, I can see a prompt flashing but nothing happens. If I open the same script with IDLE and run it, everything works fine.
To be sure the script was not executing propoerly, I made a test script like this:

```
def main():
   files = open('test.txt','a')
   files.write('this is a test')
```

The simple script write the file if launched thru idle, but nothing happens if if I double click it.
I tried with both .py and pyw extension and in more than one (windows) pc. I added the python folder to the path with no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/26045113/4014959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the script includes this snippet of code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # call your code here
    main()
```

That's the execution entry point for a script running from the command line, like the `main()` function in C/C++/Java/C#. Read more about it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) post.

Also, don't forget the obvious - give the right execution permissions to the script, make sure that the `python.exe` command is available in the `%PATH%` environment variable, and so on.