# Making a Python script executable by double-clicking

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Python script, that I want to run by executing outside of the command line, just by double-clicking it in the File Explorer. When I double-click a `.py` file now, a black command-line box appears briefly and then disappears. What do I need to write in the file to enable this?

I'd be interested in the answer for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521456/python-scripts-stopped-running-on-double-click-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux, you will  have to make the `.py` file executable

```
chmod 750 mypyprog.py
```

add the proper shebang in the first line to make the shell or file explorer know the right interpreter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('Meow :3')             # <- replace this by payload
```

If you want to review the results before the shell window is closing, a staller at the end (as shown by MackM) is useful:

```
input('Press any key...')
```

As we see from the comments, you already mastered steps 1 and 2, so 3 will be your friend.

Windows does not know about shebangs. You will have to associate the `.py` extension with the Python interpreter as described [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/windows.html#id3). The python interpreter does not have to be in the `PATH` for this because the full path can be specified there.

Answer (score -1):

Your script *is* running, and when it's done, it's closing.  To see the results, you need to add something to stall it.  Try adding this as the last line in your script:

```
staller = intput("Press ENTER to close")
```

Answer (score -1):

Using something like this file that creates a file to prove it worked

```
#somefile.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def some_definition_you_want_to_run():
    """ This will run if python is on your path """
    print("This will print, when double clicking somefile.py")
    with open('lookforme.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('you found me!')
        

#and then at the bottom of your .py do this
if __name__ == "__main__":
     some_definition_you_want_to_run()
```

WINDOWS:

Python has to be on path, and when you see the icon it should look like a piece of paper with the python logo on it. If you double click it it should create the file.

LINUX

Same file as above. Run this also.

```
$ nano run.sh
# in Nano enter `python somefile.py`
$ chmod +x run.sh
```

I think at this point run.sh is double clickable on ubuntu as long as you are logged in as the user that made this file.