# Why can't I get print()?

Tags: python

i'm new with this and i'm using Sublime Text 3 to learn python.

I'm trying to run a simple code

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
year = str((2014 - age)+100)
print(name + " will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

I tried eveything to use SublimeRepl, but when I try to run, the console only gives me "What is your name:", nothing more, even if I write a name and press enter, nothing comes from it. Then I saved and tried to run with cmd, but I only get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWMA7.png)

If I type any number, the cmd closes and I don't get the print() that is in the code. What I'm doing wrong? And why SublimeRepl doesn't work for me?

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik It has to be greater than 3

Comment: What happens if you add `input("Press ENTER to exit...")` at the end of your program (after `print`)?

Comment: Install anaconda and jupyter notebook/lab. Best environment for newbies I think :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a Python script executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045113/making-a-python-script-executable)

Comment: Hello Royalsaint, and welcome to the site.  Take a look at that duplicate I pointed you to, the question sounds different but it looks like you're actually having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that your interpreter and shell exit before you see the output. Just do as @CristiFati suggested, add an instruction that takes an additional input, that will prevent the interpreter from exiting before you see the result:

```
input("Press ENTER to exit...")
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but why I can't get the rest with the sublime console?