# Python with library pymssql can not run script with double-click

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, windows-10, double-click, pymssql

A Python script runs fine if I start it manually in a command prompt (`CMD`), e. g.

Script `P:\theproject\thescript.py`:

```
import pymssql
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = open('test.txt','a')
    files.write('this is a test')
```

Run manually:

```
C:\Users\theuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe P:\theproject\thescript.py
```

However, when double-click onto the file `thescript.py`, the command prompt opens and closes immediately without any action having taken place, i. e. the file `test.txt` is not written. This problem is similar to the [general case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234908/python-script-doesnt-work-with-double-click). However, it seems to be due to the library `pymssql` specifically. If I comment the first line (see below) and start with double-click, it runs fine, i. e. the file `test.txt` is written.

```
#import pymssql
if __name__ == "__main__":
    files = open('test.txt','a')
    files.write('this is a test')
```

Why is there a problem with `pymssql` being imported, and how can I make the script callable with double-click and `pymssql` being imported?

I'm working with Windows 10 Pro and Python version 3.9.5.

Comment: I bet it is an access issue since `test.txt` specifies a relative path. Try `import os`, then `print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))` and `raw_input()` to find out what the current directory is, even when you double-click the Python script…

Comment: This might be true. However, the same issue occurs with no file creation, e.g. with line 3 ``yourentry = input("Your entry: ")`` and line 4 ``print(yourentry)``.